# IIS: This program cannot display the webpage

Tags: iis

I have IIS installed on my remote machine. I tried to connect to the remote machine IIS using the "Computer Management --> Action --> connect to another computer" Entered the remote machine name. It's displaying the IIS with other options like System Tools and Storage. But when I select the IIS, it gives me an error page : " This program cannot display the webpage".

Please let me know if anyone is having solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a mismatch of IIS versions.  I.e. the "Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager" tool will not manage an IIS 5 instance... or vise-versa.

Comment: This is happening though if I directly connect to machine also. I open the remote machine. open IIS. Then Default Web Site . Now I browse a HTML page. It says "The Program cannot display the webpage"\

Comment: Even on the same machine, you can have different versions of the IIS management tool.